# How can I assign another m2m based on the m2m field in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to save multiple ‌`bandcolors` for each `color` I'm saving multiple colors for a `watchseries`.

Models:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True) 

class WatchSeries(models.Model):
    series          = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    colors          = models.ManyToManyField(to='Color', related_name='+')

class BandColor(models.Model):
    color           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Not sure, Do I need to create a new model like below:

```
class BandColorByWatchColor(models.Model):
    series          = models.ForeignKey('WatchSeries', related_name="+", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    color           = models.ForeignKey('Color', related_name="+", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    band_color      = models.ManyToManyField(to='BandColor', related_name="+")
```

After saving colors for individual Watch series, this is how I can see the colors and populate the BandColor for each on the right side in Django admin panel:

**Admin site code:**

```
class BandColorByWatchColorFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        kwargs['parent_object'] = self.instance
        return kwargs

class BandColorByWatchColorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    band_color = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])
    
    class Meta:
        model: BandColorByWatchColor

    def __init__(self, *args, parent_object, **kwargs):
        self.parent_object = parent_object
        super(BandColorByWatchColorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        values_list = [(x.pk, x.color) for x in BandColor.objects.all()]
        self.fields['band_color'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=values_list, required=False)

class WatchSerieColorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model   = WatchSeries.colors.through
    formset = BandColorByWatchColorFormSet
    form    = BandColorByWatchColorForm
    extra = 0

class WatchSeriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = WatchSeries
    form = WatchSeriesAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ('colors', 'repaint_colors')
    inlines = [WatchSerieColorInline]
    save_on_top = True
    list_display_links = ('series', )
    search_fields = ('series', )
    list_display = ['series', 'sku_mapping', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'is_deleted']

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = user
        instance.updated_by = user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
    
    # I tried to do something with another new model
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        bc_dict = {}
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for form in formset:
            color_id = form.instance.id
            bc_dict[color_id] =form.cleaned_data['band_color']
            instances.band_color_ids = form.cleaned_data['band_color']
        formset.save_m2m()
```

**Admin site view:**
[image]
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.